# MySQL compare two different tables with different contraints

Tags: mysql

MySQl Comparison of Two Different Tables

I have two tables with these structures:

Table 1

```
FullContact
-----------
id
name
phone
address
email
phone
registration
marketingId
created
```

Table 2

```
Contacted
-----------
first_name
last_name
email
```

The FullContact table contains people and the Contacted might contain the same individuals but is given back to me in a strange column structure.

The FullContact might contain duplicates and the Contacted has no duplicates.

Main Goal: I want to see how many from Contacted are in FullContact.

The query I am trying to run is of this form:

```
SELECT distinct fc.name, fc.email, fc.phone, concat_ws(" ",c.first_name, c.last_name),
c.phone from Contacted c 
INNER JOIN FullContact fc 
ON ( concat_ws(" ", c.first_name,
c.last_name) = fc.name or c.email = fc.email or (fc.phone REGEXP '[0-9]+$') = c.phone)   
and fc.created >= '2011-11-01';
```

Explanation of Query:
 I am trying to select the items in FullContact that are the same as Contacted by using an inner join and constraining by three string parameters and a date parameter.

Problem:
 I made the select statement to show the results of items from FullContact and items from Contacted. The results contain FullContact columns being unique and Contact values duplicating.

Is this the correct query to run?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You are checking for three lots of duplicates in there, name, email or phone.
So if you have two different names with the same email, you get two records in the result. I would have expected and in the on clause.

Comment: I was thinking that the distinct statement will offer a grouping like functionality. However, I wrote the statement incorrectly because it will only care about the fc.name column. One problem for the query is that I am trying to constrain to much to check if I am getting the correct output. I split the query into an email check, phone check, and name check. Afterwards I can check all the matches manually. This was the most efficient way I found for now.

Comment: Grouping would be an extra step. Probably be easier to understand broken up into three bits anyway.